# What is the preferred way to make mapStateToProps work with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Replacing this:

```
function mapStateToProps(appState: ApplicationState, ownProps: any): MyComponentState {
    ...
    return {
        someObject: someObject,
        isNew: isNew
    };
}
```

with this:

```
function mapStateToProps(appState: ApplicationState, ownProps: any): MyComponentState {
    ...
    return new MyComponentState(someObject, isNew);
}
```

throws the following error:

> mapStateToProps() in Connect(MyComponent) must return a plain object.
>   Instead received [object Object].

IMHO the `new CustomPageState()` has the benefit of improved readability, the ability to call constructor logic if needed, and allows for a nice way to handle optional arguments, so it feels like a nicer way to go (when working in Typescript).

**What is the recommended / best practiced way to accomplish returning a plain object in this scenario?**

Answer (score 1):

As I understand React/Redux, it appears your first code snippet is  more correctly implemented. `mapStateToProps` is supposed to return a *subset* of your state, as a plain object, to reduce overhead. Returning a fully constructed state object seems to defeat the purpose.

If you want to keep things clean in `mapStateToProps`, I would add a method to `MyComponentState` that returns a plain object. It would also seem incorrect to return `MyComponentState` type in this situation, since again, a plain object is expected. If you want a specific listing of properties for clarity, I would suggest creating an interface (ex. `IComponentStateProps`) and implementing it in your class `MyComponentState implements IComponentStateProps { ... }`

Comment: Excellent point on the subset concept! That is winning me over back to returning just a plain object as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I settled with adding `| any` to the return type.

```
mapStateToProps(appState: ApplicationState, ownProps: any): MyComponentState | any 
{
    ...
    return {
        someObject: someObject,
        isNew: isNew
    };
}
```

This allows partial objects, which as Greg pointed out is a huge benefit, but also allows visual studio to still give me code hints and Typescript to carry on.

I hope in the future there will be an even better way, or maybe someone else has some better ideas?

---

I also considered making all properties of MyComponentState optional; however, 
doing so required more truthy checks wherever these properties were used.
Since some properties really need to be required, this route would've introduced some programming maintenance confusion as well.